# Какой фреймворк\библиотека или платформа лучше для сборки GIF из кадров?

Tags: php, node.js, gif

На сервер в PHP приходят кадры для GIF в виде JSON с base64 кодом кадров.
Для сборки уже использовались два метода:

1. Использование **Sybio/GifCreator**
2. Использование **Imagick**

**Первый метод**, очень быстрый и практически не нагружает php. При 200 кадрах сборка происходит за миллисекунды. Однако замечен один минус - в GIF иногда моргают цвета в кадрах, создавая очень некрасивый эффект и этот момент портит всю картину.

**Второй метод** с использованием **Imagick**, сжирает до **200мб ОЗУ** и просто валит весь php процесс и очень долго в итоге собирает GIF, а иногда сервер просто сбрасывает соединение и прекращает работу скрипта. Однако этот метод создаёт шикарную GIF с хорошим качеством.

Возник вопрос, знает ли кто как в **Sybio/GifCreator** убрать глюки с моргающими цветами, я подозреваю что это некий механизм который объединяет похожие цвета в один что помогает сжимать размер gif, если так то как его убрать?! Либо как сделать так, чтобы **Imagick** собирал GIF быстрее и не тратил много ресурсов PHP.

Так же возможно кто то предложит другую библиотеку или фреймворк, который лучше и быстрее делают сборку GIF? Или может стоит вообще собирать GIF на **NodeJS**?

Comment: А почему бы не создавать gif асинхронно. Сначала загружаем кадры. Потом по мере освобождения конвейера делаем сборку. И можно вообще установить любую программу по сборке gif и дергать её через `exec()`

Comment: @ArchDemon проблема в том, что Imagick жрет много памяти и кладёт процесс php до разрыва соединения но делает хорошую анимацию. А первый метод работает быстро, но с дефектами.
Т.е. проблема найти решение которое не будет жрать, будет быстро выполнятся и чтоб на выходе нормальная была анимация без глюков и мерцаний цвета.
А как это решение запускать это уже другой вопрос. От асинхронности тут ничего не изменится, так же Imagick сложит весь php и всё.